# Adding Text After Price Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento

I have just launched an online clothing site using magento 1.7.0.2. I would like to add “With Free Shipping” or an image after the price on both the product and catalogue pages. I have tried the advice given in previous articles but have not had any luck.
I am using the Mercado theme from 8theme but using the template path hints the price appears to be generated by `frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` which I understand is a core magento file.

Despite this there is a short price.phtml in the Mercado theme directory. This file only contains the line `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone') ?>`. I have added an echo command below this but this has had no effect (even after a cache refresh). I have followed advice on the magento forums regarding an addition to this file but this also have no effect on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the file `frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` into the folder for the Mercado theme, and edit it there. I don't know what the exact path is for the theme you are using, but the file should end up in a location like `frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`.

BTW, I found [this site](http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-start-with-magento.html) the other day. It has lots of useful resources. One of them is the [Magento Design Guide](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf) - which has a good explanation of Magento's theme fallback model, among other things.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my reply! Yes, your solution worked perfectly. Many thanks for your assistance with this!